# when compile protocol buffer, missing input or program is not executable error

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm trying to make golang+grpc server on mac. I installed golang, grpc, protocol buffer and checked that grpc server following this example https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/go/ 
The problem is when I try to compile .proto file using protocol buffer it said 'missing input' or 'program is not executable'.

install protocol buffer and grpc

```
brew install grpc protobuf
```

install golang based protoc plugin

```
go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
```

protoc path

```
which protoc
/usr/local/bin/protoc
```

example location

```
/Users/usrname/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld
```

run proto compiler

```
protoc -I=/Users/username/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld/ --go_out=/Users/username/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld/ /Users/username/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld/helloworld.proto
```

error message

```
protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was mentioned in [`golang/protobuf` issue 795](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/795)

> See the [`Installation` section of the page `README`](https://github.com/golang/protobuf#installation):
>
> Grab the code from the repository and install the proto package.
>   The simplest way is to run `go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go`.
>
> The compiler plugin, `protoc-gen-go`, will be installed in `$GOPATH/bin` unless `$GOBIN` is set. It must be in your `$PATH` for the protocol compiler, `protoc`, to find it.

So double-check the value of your `$GOPATH` (`~/go` by default if not set)

If `$GOPATH/bin` (or `~/go/bin`) in your `$PATH`?

The [OP camilla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11896097/camila) confirms it is not:

> `$PATH` also has `:/Users/username/go/bin/protoc-gen-go`

It should have `:/Users/username/go/bin`

Comment: when I run ```go env``` it says ```GOPATH="/Users/username/go"``` so I guess GOPATH is set already

Comment: @camila OK, but is `/Users/username/go/bin` path of your `$PATH`? What does `echo $PATH` returns?

Comment: ```echo $PATH``` returns ```:/usr/local/go/bin```

Comment: @camila Do you see `protoc-gen-go` in `/usr/local/go/bin`?  Do you see `protoc-gen-go` in `/Users/username/go/bin`? Could you [add $GOPATH/bin, that is `/Users/username/go/bin`, to your PATH](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/119126)?

Comment: yes, ```echo $PATH``` also has ```:/Users/username/go/bin/protoc-gen-go``` too

Comment: @camila No: I meant: add `/Users/username/go/bin`, *not* `/Users/username/go/bin/protoc-gen-go`: you need to add the *path* to the executable, *not* the executable itself.